# Whay is Randomized_Select Algorithm in this way?

Tags: algorithm, selection

I'm studying "Introduction to Algorithms" textbook 2nd edition. In chapter 9(Medians and Order Statistics), I cannot understand why we need this extra k in Randomize_Select algorithm. Consider this pseudocode of the algorithm in the book.

```
RANDOMIZED-SELECT(A, p, r, i)
1   if p = r
2       then return A[p]
3   q ← RANDOMIZED-PARTITION(A, p, r)
4   k ← q - p + 1
5   if i = k    ▹ the pivot value is the answer
6       then return A[q]
7   elseif i < k
8       then return RANDOMIZED-SELECT(A, p, q - 1, i)
9   else return RANDOMIZED-SELECT(A, q + 1, r, i - k)
```

My question is why do we need k? I implemented the algorithm that way and it works(for all the examples I tested the algorithm on).

```
RANDOMIZED-SELECT(A, p, r, i)
1   if p = r
2       then return A[p]
3   q ← RANDOMIZED-PARTITION(A, p, r)
4   if i = q    ▹ the pivot value is the answer
5       then return A[q]
6   elseif i < q
7       then return RANDOMIZED-SELECT(A, p, q - 1, i)
8   else return RANDOMIZED-SELECT(A, q + 1, r, i)
```

Since q returned from the partition procedure is an index that contains the element from the set that it should contain after sorting, if that index is what we search for we just return it, if not we recurse the same way on the part that contains the element. Why the need for k? 
Why does the algorithm care about the order of the element within each subset? Why not we care about the index instead? Does my change work for all cases?

Comment: Did you try the algorithm at all ? A single execution should show you that your blind change is a bad idea.

Comment: I tried it and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It backs to the definition of the `i` in `RANDOMIZED-SELECT`. `i` is in the range of the passed array to the function which is started from `p` to `r` of the array `A`. Hence, the selected value `q` should be computed from the specified first of the array `A`. Hence, we should compute `k` (a location in the passed array) related to the starting index which is `p`.

Moreover, as the index is `1` based here, the `k` should be `q - p + 1`.

For example, Suppose `A` is a array with size of 10, and `p = 5,` `r = 8`. Therefore, `i` is changed from `1` to `3`. Hence, we should map the `q` which is between `5` and `8` should be scaled from `1` to `3`; so, `k` has the same scale as `i` that `q` has not!

Comment: Thanks much for tour answer. But what do you mean by "i is the location of the element the passed array A"?

Comment: @HosamAbdelnaser it's updated. I mean `i` is in the range of the passed array which is from `p` to `r` of the array `A`.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand what you mean

Comment: Yes, with pleasure too.